# Maven: Show dependency tree for specific artifact without adding it to pom

Tags: maven, dependency-management

For showing the dependency tree of an existing project (with a `pom.xml`), there's [mvn dependency:tree](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html).

But sometimes, I want to have a look at the dependencies without having to create a `pom.xml` and adding the dependency there.

So, is there a command for showing the dependency tree of a specific groupId:artifactId:version without having an existing project?

(I'd also be happy if there is another tool that has something for this, maybe Gradle.)

Comment: I don't think there is existing support for that in maven

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You definitely need a pom for resolving dependencies, that's where dependency information is stored. But you can workaround having a project:

1. Get the pom of your artifact:

   ```
   mvn dependency:get \
   -Dartifact=groupId:artifactId:version:pom \
   -DremoteRepositories=default::http://repo.url... \
   -Dtransitive=false -Ddest=pom.xml
   ```
2. Run `mvn dependency:tree`.

This worked for me. Or using dependency:copy:

1. Run `dependency:copy`:

   ```
   mvn dependency:copy \
   -Dartifact=groupId:artifactId:version:pom \
   -DoutputDirectory=.
   ```
2. `mv artifactId-version.pom pom.xml`.
3. Run `mvn dependency:tree`.

Comment: Thanks! This worked on mvn 3.2.2 (not on mvn 3.0.5), but seems like it will be going away: `[WARNING] destination/dest parameter is deprecated: it will disappear in future version.`

Comment: Sorry, I'm updating my answer to avoid using that deprecated method. About not working in 3.0.5, be sure to use maven-dependency-plugin 2.8: you can force it using: `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:get`

Comment: I think the first point of the second list should read `dependency:copy`, right? Also, you could get rid of the second step by making the third step be `mvn -f artifactId-version.pom dependency:tree`.